# Track changes to library with git

Tags: git

For a magento2 project I need to make changes to the magento core files since currently even small bugfixes there seem to take (literally) years.

My idea was to add files I need to change to master, then make the changes in a seperate branch ("hacks") and merge them back to master with --no-ff option (obviously I need the changes in master an cannot have them unmerged).

What I don't archieve now is seeing the list of commits of branch "hacks" only since becaue I merged them into master all commits belong to master as well.

I there a way to do this, or should I just do the whole thing differently?

Comment: This might be a use case for [StGit](http://procode.org/stgit/), [Guilt](https://linux.die.net/man/7/guilt) or [tag:quilt]

Comment: try `gitk [filename]` or `gitk --follow [filename]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `gitk [filename]` or `gitk --follow [filename]`

Comment: I had rather something telling git to "show all commits originally committed in branch X". This works for now but I can image situations where it fails, too.

Comment: Try this `git log origin/dev..HEAD` `dev`=branch name